# Are those two theories about universes equivalent?

Tags: set-theory, axioms, large-cardinals, alternative-set-theories

If we define a universe as a well founded extensional transitive set that is closed under power, union, and non-bigger than, formally this is:

$\mathbf U (X) \iff  \forall a \in X: \\ \forall m \in a (m \in X)  \\\forall b \in X :\forall z (z \in b \leftrightarrow z \in a) \to a=b   \\\forall S \subseteq X \exists m \in S: \forall n \in S (n \not \in m)  \\  \exists c,d \in X : c=\mathcal P(a),  d=\bigcup(a)  \\\forall k \subseteq X (|k| \not > |a| \implies k \in X)$

Where: $|k| > |a| \iff \exists f: a \hookrightarrow k \land \not \exists g: k \hookrightarrow a$

Where $``\hookrightarrow"$ signify *injection*; and $``\mathcal P, \bigcup"$ standing for powerset and set unions defined in the usual manner.

And if we add the following axioms on top of mono-sorted first order logic with equality and membership.

**1. Universes:** $\forall x \exists w: \mathbf U(w) \land x \in w$

*Every set belongs to some universe.*

**2. Separation:** $\forall a \exists b: b=\{x \in a: \phi\}$, where $\phi$ doesn't use $``b"$.

Then this would prove $ZFC$ over universes higher than $V_\omega$. If we want to prove $ZF+GC$ over those universes, then we'll need to modify the size condition in the definition of universes to:

$\forall k \subseteq X (|k| \neq |X| \implies k \in X)$

Where: $|k|=|X| \iff \exists f: k \hookrightarrow X \land \exists g: X \hookrightarrow k $

Call this theory as *Universes Theory*, to be denoted by $\sf UT$.

To get ZFC we need to add the axiom of Largeness:

**3. Largeness:** $\forall x \exists w: |w| > |x| \land \forall u \in w (\mathbf U(u))$

*Every set is strictly smaller than a set of universes.*

I think that all sentences of [$\sf TG$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory) set theory would be provable in this system, so this is just a reformulation of it.

However, the axiom of largeness seems to be more of a fix. I think a more principled axiom would be the following:

**3. Generalization:** $(\forall w: \mathbf U(w) \to \phi^w) \implies \phi$,

Where $\phi^w$ is a sentence with all of its quantifiers bounded $\in w$, and $w$ not used otherwise.

In English: *what is true inside all universes is true in the whole world!*

> Is the generalization axiom consistent with the first two?

> Are both theories ($\sf UT+Larg.; UT+Gen.$) equivalent?

Comment: Your *generalization* looks like a kind of reflection principle.

Comment: @HanulJeon, I'm not really sure of that point. In reflection we start with a formula $\phi$ that is true in the whole world and then we reflect inside and say that there is some $V_\kappa$ inside that world where $\phi$ is true *inside* it. But here the direction seems to be in the opposite, that is if $\phi$ is shared between *all* universes, then it generalize to the whole world, so we begin from what is inside the universes and go to the whole world, while in reflection we begin from the whole world and go inside one of the universes. So I'm not sure if one can use reflection to prove Gen.

Comment: Does $GC$ mean global choice?

Comment: The theory UT, with universes defined using the second version of the size condition, apparently doesn't prove extensionality between different universes. It doesn't even rule out that there are two disjoint universes.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson, $GC$ means global choice. You are right! UT doesn't prove extensionality. I think this may be fixed if we forbid existence of more than one empty object.

Comment: Even if there is a unique empty set, there may be two universes with the different singletons of the empty set (also, now I see that the same problem applies to the first version of the size condition one universes). However, with the axiom of replacement we could prove that every two sets are in a common universe, and that would prove extensionality globally.

Comment: Actually, the axiom of pairing would be enough to prove extensionality over this theory.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson, the two singletons would be elements of both universes by axiom of size and so they'll be extensional. So, I think existence of one empty set would do it, I don't know why I think that this theory can prove extensionality, through foundation, and taking the least violation, which would be a subset of all universes and so extensionality works. Notice that the UT does prove that there can only be ONE empty set.

Comment: I see. So UT does prove extensionality after all.

Comment: @ArvidSamuelsson. Yes! I think so. But, I didn't formally prove it, so I'm not so sure. I think the basic idea is we take a universe U suppose it has elements that violated extensionality with some other universe W, now work in U take the lowest rank at which such a set appear as a subset of, then that rank has all of its elements being extensional over all universes, so it'll be a subset of W, now let K be a universe such that $W \in K$, then extensionality would be violated in K, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

+. is inconsistent.

We note that if () and  is th least ordinal not in X, then X=.

Proof:Suppose X is not a subset of . Let Y={x∈X | x∉}. There is y∈Y such that for all x∈Y, x∉y. There is a set A, such that ∈A iff  is the least ordinal such that x∈ for some x∈y,. Then A is in X.
Therefore UA is in X. But x⊆(UA) and thus x∈. Suppose  is not a subset of X. Let B={x∈| x is not a subset of X}. Let  be the least element of B. There is a set W={(t+1)|t∈B}. But UW∈X and
=UW.

Let b be a function with domain ω, which enumerates those x such that "x is a sentence" holds, and  "x does not hold in every universe" holds.

For every n∈ω, there is a least ordinal n such that n is a universe, Universes holds in n, and for all m∈(n+1), there is a universe X in n for which  "bm does not hold in X".

Proof:Let N be the set of n∈ω such that there is a least ordinal n such that (n), Universes holds in n, and for all m∈(n+1), there is a universe X in n such that  "bm does not hold in X".
Universes holds and there is an X such that (X) and "b0 does not hold in X". By Generalization, there must be Y such that (Y) and
Universes holds in Y and ("there is an X such that (X) and "b0 does not hold in X") holds in Y. 0 is the least such universe. Suppose that k∈N. If "b(k+1) doe not hold in X" for some universe X∈k,
then (k+1)=k. Suppose ("b(k+1) doe not hold in X" and (X)) implies X∉k. Universes holds and there is an X such that (X) and "b(k+1) does not hold in X". By Generalization, there must be Y
such that (Y), Universes  holds in Y, and (there is an X such that (X) and "b(k+1) does not hold in X") holds in Y. (k+1) is the least such Y. Therefore N=ω.

Suppose "S is a finite set of sentences" holds. For each  in S, there is a "Generalization sentence" for . Let T be the set of those "Generalization sentences". Then Con(+T)

Proof: If ∈S  and " does not hold in every universe" holds, then  is bm for some m. There is an n∈ω, such that if bm∈S, then m<n since "S is finite" holds. Then "UT"+T holds in n.

Since the consistency of every "finite subtheory of +." is provable in +., Con(+) is provable in +.. Therefore +. is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer to this question.

For the second question it appears that $\sf UT + Gen$ is stronger than $\sf TG$ set theory because I think it proves the existence (among its elements) of a universe that doesn't have a set of all universes in it, more specifically a universe that is the union of inaccessibly many universes below it, this universe would satisfy all sentence of $\sf TG$ and thus would prove $\sf Con(TG)$. This very same universe would also satisfy all sentences of $\sf UT+ Larg$. However, I don't know where the consistency strength of that theory would stop, or even if its consistent either?